# Angular, Jasmine mock whole module dependiences," is not available!" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

In my module i have some dependiences:

```
var app = angular.module('action', ['xeditable']);
```

Angular-xeditable is a bundle of AngularJS directives that allows you to create editable elements. more: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

End no i my Jasmine test i want to mock all this module. 
I was trying like this:

```
var mocks;
beforeEach(function() {
    mocks = jasmine.createSpyObj("mocks", ["xeditable"]);

    module("action", function($provide){
        $provide.value('xeditable', mocks.xeditable)
    });
});
```

but i still get:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'xeditable' is not available!
```

I know that there were a lot of questions about it but do not know how to deal, very please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solved it, just added another beforeEach before load module, like that:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  //mock the xeditable lib:
  angular.module("xeditable", []);
});

beforeEach(function() {
  module("action");
});
```